# RegEx check for Spanish Characters

Tags: .net, regex, unicode

We currently have a regEx expression in one of our .net infragistics Text controls that allows for all English characters to be entered.

The problem now is that we have a Spanish speaking user using the system and therefore they need to be able to enter the non-English Spanish alphabet characters into the textbox.

How do I add the Spanish alphabet characters into our RegEx check expression?

Comment: Would be good to see your current regex. You may add Ñ to your set of letters.

Comment: Define “Spanish characters”. Once you have done that, the rest is trivial. Defining the set of characters used in a language is very difficult and even controversial. So the main question here is not really about programming. It might indirectly relate to programming, though: when defining the set, it might be relevant to know *why* you need a specific set of characters to be allowed? Or, in other words: why do you want to disallow some characters?

Answer (score 1):

What about allowing all letters in all languages? There is Unicode and you can match for Unicode characters with certain properties.

For letters there is the property `\p{L}`.

You can use this as it is in regex:

- `\p{L}+` to match a sequence of letters
- `[\p{L}_]+` in a character class

There are also Unicode scripts and blocks, that define a certain subset of Unicode characters/letters, maybe that is more what you want, e.g. `\p{Greek}` or `\p{Cyrillic}`. I don't know what would be the subset for spanish.

For some more details see e.g.

- An overview about [Unicode and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) from Jon Skeet
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for an overview over the properties/scripts/blocks
- Chapter "Unicode Category or Unicode Block: `\p{}`" in the articel [**Character Classes in Regular Expressions** on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)